# Detecting 1st Directory if its not english

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a website where its got translated languages which are the following.

English, German, Spanish, French and Italian.

I have a select box which when selected it should change the location to the translated language.

the main issue I'm having is figuring out how to get the url WITHOUT the translated directory name in the url.

So far I have

```
var curURL = $('#flagsectionurl').attr('value');
var n=curURL.split("/");        
console.log(n[1]);
```

The input#flasgectionurl picks up the current page url. So if I'm looking at

> domain.com/de/index

the console.log will show 'de'

When the select box is chosen it currently does the following

```
var chosenCountry = data.selectedData.value;
window.location = "/"+chosenCountry+$('#flagsectionurl').attr('value');
```

What would be the best method to change the directory whilst retaining the current page? As this method does not work as it ends up going to domain.com/de/de/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a new country to the URL but not removing the current one.

You start with your `chosenCountry` variable and then you are appending the current URL `$('#flagsectionurl').attr('value')` which already contains a country.

You want to replace the country part of the URL whilst retaining the rest of it. To do this you could do the following (based on the structure of your URLs shown in your code that logs to the console):

```
var new_url = $('#flagsectionurl').attr('value');
new_url = url.split("/"); 
new_url[1] = data.selectedData.value;
window.location = new_url.join("/");
```

**Edit:**

Because of the issue you have raised where for English it does not use the above URL convention, you need to keep track of the current language (including if it is English), if you have not already. Then if the current selection is English and you are changing to another language, you will need to add a new item to the array after splitting it. If you are going from another language to English, you will need to remove the item in the array at position 1.

```
var new_lang = data.selectedData.value;
var new_url = $('#flagsectionurl').attr('value');
new_url = url.split("/");
if (cur_lang == 'en') {
    new_url.splice(1,0,new_lang);
}
else if (new_lang == 'en') {
    new_url.splice(1,1);
}
else {
    new_url[1] = new_lang;
}
window.location = new_url.join("/");
```

The above code works off the assumption the current language and new language cannot be the same, you will need to check for this if you are not already.

Comment: Looking at that, it should work but what if when I select English version? It should goto the Root as english isn't in a directory of its own